# Problema con un .jar en java no me carga los componentes

Tags: java, ireport, jar

Cree un .jar en java usando Netbeans y por alguna razón al ponerlo a correr en otro PC funciona de maravilla, el único problema es que usa un JDesktopPane y no puede ejecutar las ventanas interiores, todas las ventanas que son capaces de ejecutarse sin más no tienen problemas, pero las que van dentro no corren, además tampoco me lanza reportes en ireport, no sé que podrá ser. cuando trato de abrir alguna de las ventanas me marca un "null pointer exception" significa que no encuentra lo que busca, pero me aseguré de encapsular todo el proyecto en el .jar así que no sé que podría ir mal ¿Alguna idea?

Actualización:
Me di cuenta que funcionan una ventanas y otras no, seguramente es porque toma los datos desde la carpeta src y no debería tomar esa ruta, puesto que cuando se compila en el .jar esa carpeta queda de lado, pero no sé como encontrar la ruta donde se define la raíz de los archivos incluidos en el proyecto.

Comment: que característica tiene el pc y que versión de java

Comment: Se utilizan dos pc uno de 32 bits y uno de 64 bits que es con el que se hace el sistema, la versión que se usa de java es la 1.8.0.251 - Sin embargo no creo que ese sea el problema, puesto que el sistema funciona en el otro dispositivo, lo único que no es capaz de llamar a las otras pantallas

Comment: pero la version del jdk de los equipos

Comment: he encontrado  varias problemas con los jdk a partir de la 7 bloquea componentes y lo debes desactivar te lo voy a poner en respuesta a ver si te vale

Comment: Solamente estoy usando un jdk y es desde el equipo de 64 bits que es donde desarrolle la aplicación, el otro pc usa jre. El equipo de donde desarrollé tiene el jdk en la versión 1.8.0.251

Answer (score 0):

Enlace del error encontrado : https://www.java.com/es/download/help/error_mixedcode.xml

**Resumen:**

**SÍNTOMAS**

Al intentar ejecutar un applet o una aplicación basados en Java, aparece un cuadro de diálogo de advertencia de seguridad:

**CAUSA**

Las aplicaciones y los applets Java Web Start firmados que contienen componentes firmados y no firmados podrían ser potencialmente inseguros, a menos que el fabricante de la aplicación así lo haya diseñado. A partir de la versión Java SE 6 Actualización 19, cuando un programa contiene componentes firmados y no firmados, aparece un cuadro de diálogo de advertencia.

**SOLUCIÓN**

En el cuadro de diálogo de seguridad, si el usuario hace clic en Sí, se bloquean los componentes potencialmente no seguros para evitar que se ejecuten y el programa puede cerrarse. Si el usuario hace clic en el botón No, la aplicación o el applet continúa ejecutándose.
Las advertencias aparecen por defecto, aunque los usuarios disponen de opciones para controlar esta situación.

Puede gestionar la forma en que se manejan los programas de código mixto en el panel de control de Java.

Opciones de protección de código mixto en el panel de control de Java
En el panel de control de Java, haga clic en el separador Avanzadas.
Amplíe la opción Verificación de seguridad de código mixto (sandbox frente a de confianza) de la sección Seguridad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay cuatro niveles de control disponibles.
**Habilitar:** mostrar advertencia si es preciso
Ésta es la configuración por defecto. Cuando se detecta un riesgo potencial, aparece un cuadro de diálogo de advertencia. Al hacer clic en Sí, se bloquean los componentes potencialmente no seguros para evitar que se ejecuten y el programa puede cerrarse. Si el usuario hace clic en No, la aplicación o el applet continúan ejecutándose con protección (los paquetes o recursos que se encuentren posteriormente con los mismos nombres pero diferentes niveles de confianza, por ejemplo, firmados vs. no firmados, no se cargarán).

**Habilitar:** ocultar advertencia y ejecutar con protección
Esta opción suprime el cuadro de diálogo de advertencia. El código se ejecuta, del mismo modo que si el usuario hubiera hecho clic en No en el cuadro de diálogo de advertencia.

**Habilitar:** ocultar advertencia y no ejecutar código que no sea de confianza
Esta opción suprime el cuadro de diálogo de aviso y se comporta como si el usuario hubiera hecho clic en Sí en el cuadro de diálogo de advertencia.

**Desactivar verificación**
Esta opción no se recomienda. Con esta opción, el software no comprueba la mezcla de código de confianza con el que no es de confianza, por lo que el usuario puede ejecutar código potencialmente no seguro sin protección.

Comment: En realidad no son esos los sintomas, lo que hace es lanzarme un null pointer exception

Comment: me puedes pasar el codigo para mirarlo

Comment: El código no importa la verdad, imagina cualquier tipo de código implementado en netbeans que compilas, pero ahora resulta que no funciona del todo en el pc de 32bits, osea abren dos o 3 ventanas pero no las ventanas insertas en desktoppane, debe ser un problema de lectura. pero la pregunta es cual.

Comment: pues no lo se entonces porque en el de 64bits dijiste que te iba bien no ?

Comment: En los dos va bien, pero no carga los formularios que van dentro del jdesktoppane

Comment: entonces no tengo ni idea siento por no poder ayudarte

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112223/discussion-between-esteban-illanes-and-javier-g-raya).